# Generate subset of data with known mean

Tags: matlab, subset, mean

I have a dataset of n observations (nx1 vector) and would like to create a subset of this data, whose mean is known in advance, by selecting at random only n/3 observations (or within some constraint, ie where the mean of the data subset is within a range about the known mean).

Can someone please help me with the code do this in matlab? 
Note, I don't want to use the rand function to create random data as I already have my data collected.

For example on a smaller scale: If I had the following dataset of 12 observations:

```
data =  [8;7;4;6;9;6;4;7;3;2;1;1];
```

but then wanted to randomly select a subset of this data containing only 4 observations with a mean of 4 (or with a mean between 3.5-4.5 for example):

Then the answer might be `datasubset=[7;3;2;4]` but the answer could also be `datasubset=[6;4;2;4]` or `datasubset=[6;4;3;4]`.

It doesn't matter if there are several possible solutions, I just need one of them, though I'd like to know the alternative solutions also.

Comment: In one place you say randomly select, and in another you say any answer that fits works, what do you mean by randomly select? an algorithm to match value pairs together is pretty straightforward, but to randomly select a subset is another layer of difficulty

Comment: There are `2^12` possible subsets of 12 observations. You can generate all of them and select only the ones with means within your range, then select a random subset out of those. If the size of your dataset is much larger than 12, you can see that this approach becomes untenable very quickly.

Comment: Actually, if you know the exact number of observations you want in your subset, there are only `nchoosek` subsets where `n` is the number of observations and `k` is the length of the subset.

Comment: @beaker Thanks, I have 1200 observations in the main dataset and need a subset with 400 data points.

Comment: This is the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem and is NP-complete. You might want to think of another way of selecting your subsets. In fact, depending on how many valid subsets you expect there to be, simply selecting a random subset until you find one within range might be a better choice.

Comment: A trick can be to sort your data, take sample closest to the mean you want and then take samples right and left to this value.
That's intuitively what you are doing when you find your example subsets by hand.
Monitoring how the mean evolves, you can chose to take the samples more to the right or to the left of your central value. (But this solution is not a random choice...)

Comment: Ah yes good suggestion @beaker. So in the end I'm using randsample to randomly select a subset of n observations and then checking the subset against all of my constraints (I have a further 4 constraints the subset needs to meet besides the mean) in a while loop until the requirements are satisfied. Seems to be working exactly how I want it to.